# Entity Framework 6.1 returns null on spatial queries (using MsSQL)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, spatial

I am writing an MVC application with Entity Framework, spatial data and MsSQL 2012 that maps buildings. What I want to achieve is fairly simple.

Person clicks building on the map and gets the building details.

So I've written the following function.

```
 public BuildingPart GetByPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        DbGeometry point = DbGeometry.PointFromText("POINT(" + x + " " + y + ")", 2100);
        BuildingPart result = _context.BuildingPart
            .Where(a => a.BuildingPartPolygonGeometry.geometry.Intersects(point))
            .Include(a => a.Storey)
            .Include(a => a.RoofSurface.Select(c => c.RoofSurfacePolygon)).SingleOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
```

The thing is that although this function always returns null in the application, regardless where the user clicks. If I do take the query produced by this function and execute it on MSSQL Management studio the query does return results;

Any Other function that does not have a spatial query in its body...works.

I've tried a lot of things, among several placing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll in the project, SqlServerSpatial.dll and SqlServerSpatial110.dll in the bin folder.

The fact that I do not get a particular error is what worries me. If anyone can shed a light it will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does it return result[S] in Management Studio or one result. Because of the SingleOrDefault() two lines would give you null

Comment: it does indeed for some odd reason returns 2 results but still changing the function to return a List, or removing the includes (which then returns a single result) did not solve the problem. I still get null

Comment: Could you post the BuildingPartPolygonGeometry and BuildingPart classes or at least the relevant subset of them?

Comment: you say *If I do take the query produced by this function* how are you getting that query? are you inspecting it from the code, using a sql profiler, or building the query based on how it should act? FWIW a sql profiler would be my preferred method.

Comment: @Madullah I am using HR Entity Framework Profiler